# AD - deploying printers to XP machines, pushprinterconnections.exe errror

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, printing, windows-server-2012

I'm a newbie in AD domain administration.
I'd like to deploy our printers to client workstations mostly running WXP.
Windows Server 2012, added Print Management feature, followed a tutorial on deploying printers using Group Policies. Printer is connected via a TCP/IP port.

Windows Server 2008/2012 do not contain pushprinterconnections.exe by default. Addded pushprinterconnections.exe from pmcmgmt.exe package from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7045#Overview and put it to a new group policy logon script.

When user log in, the error "_ftol2_sse entry point not found in dynamic library msvcrt.dll" is displayed. Printer is visible in Printers/Faxes but does not print (throwing the error above).

Fresh XP installation nor installing Visual C++ redistributable 2010 didn't help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There are at least 3 methods to deploy printers via GP. How about telling us what method you're using. In addition, have you installed the GPP CSE for Windows XP on the Windows XP clients? - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3628

Comment: Thanks for the link! It helped me with another things (i.e. mapping shares without the script calling net use).
However pushprintconnections.exe error is still displayed.
I followed the tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kff2kkPAQ94 - starting from 3:00 (related to Windows Server 2008) - in 2012 it was almost the same.

Comment: I'm thinking that you don't need to use pushprinterconnections.exe with GPP.

Comment: But without it the Printers and Faxes in XP are empty. (Tested now on a fresh AD user.)

The users who already ran pushprintconnections.exe have the printer installed but not working. (_ftol2_sse entry point... error when trying to print).

I'm going to google for other printer deploying methods. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There weren't *additional* 32bit printer drivers installed on the 64bit server.

This was obviously the cause of that strange error - pushprinterconnections.exe ran deployed to 32bit XP and tried to communicate with the printer...